# Fit fixed width into mobile device viewport

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

was reading about this everywhere, but can't find a cross-device, cross-browser solution.

We've got a page that has fixed width = 600px, and we would like it to always fit device width. For example, on a 480px resolution it would be scaled 0.8, on 320px it would be scaled 0.533.

I've tried with viewport and setting initial-scale via javascript (get screen width, calculate ratio, set viewport content to "width=device-width, initial-scale=calculated-ratio"), but it mostly doesn't work as expected.

Does anyone has a real-life solution for this?

Comment: do you want it scale down when browser width is less then 600px...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, we've figured it out. It appears, that when you set initial-scale in the viewport meta tag, then you're unable to change it via JS. So the solution is to place a viewport only with width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=600">
```

and then, directly under this line place a script to update viewport with the proper scale ratio:

```
viewportElement.setAttribute( 'content', 'initial-scale=' + ratio );
```

So that's how you fit a fixed width page into the mobile viewport :)

Comment: ratio is not defined, viewportElement is not defined. How fix it?

Comment: @stiv: The solution for me was to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> var viewportElement= document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]"); var ratio = window.innerWidth/600; viewportElement.setAttribute( 'content', 'initial-scale=' + ratio );`

Answer (score 2):

Try in head:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" />`

To ensure that user can't zoom use

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you looking for this ...?
Use media querys

first make width 100% and then set width:600px when device width is greater than 600px.

```
[Demo ](http://jsfiddle.net/H9MWM)
```

Comment: hey cJ_, thanks, but it's not about media-queries and 100% width. The page itself is fixed width, has all it's elements positioned absolutely, so 100% is not the way to go here.